# Shiny set selected in selectInput according to URL parameter?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my small application, I want to get the parameter from the URL and assign it to `selected` parameter inside `selectInput` function:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("timezone_offset", "Timezone: UTC", choices = -12:14, selected = query[["my_param"]]),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please advise how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using:

```
observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query[["default_tz_offset"]])) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "timezone_offset", selected = query[["default_tz_offset"]])
    }
  })
```